# Single Jenkins Computer/Node used by more then one Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-agent

I am curios if it's possible to have one computer/node that would be shared between two jenkins instances?

I know that one can make two same copies of node configurations on Jenkins instances and change workspace, but I am aiming for this scenario.

Jenkins **A** with Node **A**
Jenkins **B** with Node **A**

Jenkins **A** starts job on Node **A**
Jenkins **B** puts Node **A** offline

Jenkins **B** starts job on Node **A**
Jenkins **A** puts Node **A** offline

Node **A** can only be used once at a time, and there should not be parallel jobs running no matter of different workspaces.

I know that it can be achieved when you have one jenkins instance, but how to do it if you have to use two of them at least?

NOTE: both Jenkins instances are located on different machines.

Comment: It's perfectly possible to have multiple Jenkins instances on one machine, but what would be the point of having two instances if you can only run one at any one time?! What happens if `A` is running a build when `B` puts it "offline"?

Comment: Jenkins instances are each on their own individual machine, but they are connecting to third party computer/node, and that computer/node (or should I say Node A from this example) can only handle one connection at the time.

Comment: So what's the point in having multiple machines? Just use one and a single build agent?

Comment: For example great number of jobs/nodes and want to split into two jenkins but still keep possibility that every job can connect to any computer/node. Example was simplification.

Comment: there is an RSS feed option in the jenkins home page...you can read it from there if a particular job is running, also you can give this a try https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/URLTrigger+Plugin

Comment: Could work. But the problem with this could be race conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [jenkins mesos plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Mesos+Plugin) is what you needed.

Use following steps to install & configure:

- step1
  [image]
- step2
  [image]
- step3
  [image]
- step4
  [image]

Of course, you had to install a mesos cluster for yourself before do above, see [mesos official site](http://mesos.apache.org/getting-started/). This may cost some time if you are not familar with mesos.

And in step4, you'd better set `slave cpus` equal with the number of your real slave node.

The principle is:

Mesos first sends resource offer to Jenkins Master A, then jenkins master A will launch tasks on the slave node A, as the resource was used by jenkins master A now. Resource offer will not be sent to Jenkins Master B again, so Jenkins Master B is waiting.

After Jenkins Master A finish task, mesos resource offer for slave node A will be sent to Jenkins Master B, then Jenkins Master B can start task.

The slave can be used by Jenkins Mesos A & Jenkins Mesos B, but never at the same time.

Hope it help you.